# TextBox and List<T> in C#

Tags: c#

Как из `TextBox` добавить значение в `List<T>`?
Надо добавить несколько разных значений. Все значения должны вводится не сразу. Промежуток будет неделя, чтобы подсчитать среднее значение для месяц!

Comment: Вы отредактировали вопрос спустя 1,5 года. Он еще актуален для Вас? Если да, то надо проголосовать за переоткрытие. Но суть его всё равно не понятна. Нужно добавлять больше подробностей в вопросы.

Comment: да нет просто как то скучно стало вот я и решил поменять текст вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Значения в `List<T>` добавляются с помощью вызовов методов `.Insert(item)` и `.Add(item)` в том числе и несколько раз.
Надо сначала определиться какого типа будет `List<T>`и какого типа значения будут добавляться. Если добавляться будет значения свойства `TextBox1.Text`, то удобнее если список будет типа `List<string>`.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
```

Добавлять можно будет командой   `list.Add(TextBox1.Text)` очень много раз.

Comment: так не получится,надо вводить ни одна значения а несколько разных значений,и то все должны вводится не сразу,а скажем промежуток будет неделя,что бы подсчитать среднее значение на месяц??

Comment: @VardanVardanyan: А вот это уже интереснее. Дополните этим уточнением свой вопрос.